# Context Free Grammar For Complement Of { wwwww | ... } With Minimal Locality?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, context-free

#### Definitions

Let $G$ be a context free grammar over an alphabet $\Sigma$ with non-terminals $V$.

- Define the locality $l(G)$ as the length of the longest word in $(V \cup \Sigma)^*$ that has a derivation tree in $G$ where no path contains the same non-terminal symbol twice. Since $V$ is finite, this number exists for every grammar $G$.

When a word in $L(G)$ that is longer than the locality of $G$ is pumped according to the pumping lemma for context free languages, there exists a pumped word that is not longer than the sum of the length of the previous word and the locality of $G$. Such a word must have a loop, and extending this loop can only make the word so much longer.

- Define the locality $l(L)$ of a language $L$ as the smallest value $l(G)$ for any grammar $G$ with $L(G) = L$, or $\infty$ if such a number does not exist. Clearly, a language is context free if and only if such a number exists.
- For a language $L$ and $N \subseteq \mathbb{N} \ni 0$, define $L^{\cap N} := \{ w \in L \; | \; |w| \in N \}$ as the set of words in $L$ whose lengths are in $N$.
- For a number $n$, define $P_n := \{ w \in \Sigma^* \; | \; \forall v \in \Sigma^*: v^n \neq w \}$ as the set of words that are not the $n$th power of another word.

#### Locality Upper Bound

We can show that $P_n = \{ w \in \Sigma^* \; | \; |w| \not\in n\mathbb{N} \lor \exists i: w_i \neq w_{i+|w|/n}  \}$.

With this insight, it is easy to show that $P_n$ is context free for all numbers $n$. (Ensure that every word $w$ has the form $w = xaybz$ for different characters $a$ and $b$ and $(n - 1) \cdot |y| + (n - 2) = |xz|$. To extend the word, add an arbitrary character to $y$ and $n - 1$ times many arbitrary characters to either $x$ or $z$. This can easily be implemented as CFG)

The locality of this grammar is less than $2 \cdot n$, which establishes an upper bound for $l(P_n)$.

#### Locality Lower Bound

Because $0^k \in P_n$ for $k \not\in n\mathbb{N}$, we can show that the locality of $P_n$ is at least $n$, by pumping that word into $(\Sigma^*)^{\cap n\mathbb{N}}$ ([as described here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/49187/34840)).
Unfortunately, this argument does not yield much insight and breaks for reasoning about the locality of $P_n \setminus (0^* | 1^*)$.

#### Open (?) Conjectures

1. Let $L$ be a language with $L^{\cap \{500\}} = P_5^{\cap \{500\}}$. Then $l(L) \geq 5$.

I would find it equally interesting to see a proof or a counter-example of this very concrete conjecture. Intuitively it feels impossible that a grammar with a locality of 4 or less can check if there exists a position $i$ such that $w_i \neq w_{i+100}$ (assuming the word-length is 500).
As $L$ could be finite, pumping arguments don't work directly.

2. $l(P_n \setminus (0^* | 1^*)) \geq n$

I believe this to be true and hope to find a more insightful argument than used for showing that $l(P_n) \geq n$.

3. For a prime number $p$, let $L$ be a language with $L^{\cap \{p^k \; | \;k \in \mathbb{N} \}} = P_p^{\cap \{p^k \; | \;k \in \mathbb{N} \}}$. Then $l(L) \geq p$.

This conjecture would imply that the set of primitive words $Q$ has an infinite locality, i.e. is not context free, as $L$ in this conjecture can be instantiated with $Q$ for every $k$.

---

I consider this SE question answered when at least one of those conjectures has been proven or disproven, as they are all related.

Comment: Note that proving 1. is not so easy because the set of primitive words $Q$
 is such that: $\forall p,q \text{ primes } Q^{\cap pq}=P_p^{\cap pq}$
. So a "generic" technique for 1. would probably suffice to prove that Q
 is not CF (which is a long-standing open question).

Comment: I think 1. is a much easier question. If I'm not mistaken, there are only finitely many languages with $l(L) < 5$ and theoretically all these cases could be checked by a computer. Also, your equality is incorrect, otherwise $P_p^{\cap pq} = P_q^{\cap pq}$, which is not the case for $p \neq q$

Comment: yes you're right, they are not equal, $\forall p,q \text{ primes } Q^{\cap pq}=P_p^{\cap pq} \cup P_q^{\cap pq}$. There are finitely many languages with $l(L) < 5$ and you can check them one by one, but *perhaps* a more general technique could be applied to the primitive words problem. I'll think more about it.

Comment: I think it should be an intersection, not union, and I think this can be generalized for arbitrary prime factorization.

Comment: I believe it is $Q^{\cap p_1^{v_1} \cdot ... \cdot ... p_n^{v_n} =: k} = P_{p_1}^k \cap ... \cap P^k_{p_n}$

Comment: yes it's the intersection and it can be extended for arbitrary prime factorization ... nice!